# example of a particular type of graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am searching for those classes of graphs where distance between any two vertices of the graph is $d$. Are there such type of graphs, after leaving the $Complete Graphs, K_n$.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say no. If the graph is not complete, there are going to be two nodes $a$,$b$ without an edge $(a,b)$. Pick a path from $a$ to $b$, and let $n > 1$ be its length. Then the distance from $a$ to $b$ is $nd \neq d$. Unless of course, $d=0$, i.e. unless you assign the weight $0$ to every edge.

This assumes that the graph is connected. If you require distance $d$ *only* for vertices which are reachable from one another, possible solutions are graphs whose connected components are complete graphs.

Comment: you are right.... i got the point. Thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 5):

There are no such class of graphs except for d=1.

Say a graph for d=2 exists. $d(a,c)=2$. There must be a path $a-b-c$. So $d(a,b)=1$.

Comment: O yeah..... very common fundamental..... didnt strike my mind.. thanks a lot